# JavaScript subclassing in Parse.com

Tags: javascript, java, android, parse-platform

In Android I subclassed `ParseObject` with two local variables that are not in Parse class. I just needed to set those variables locally and had no need to save them on server. They are `String`'s named `helper1` and `helper2` with getters and setters as well.

It works all fine on Android - I can use `setHelper1("whatever");` as well as `getHelper()` methods on my `ParseObject`'s.

What I want to do is to do the same in JavaScript since I want to make same operation in `ParseCloud` and make it return results with that additional `Strings` without creating additional columns in database class.

I read https://parse.com/docs/js/guide#objects-parse-object and https://parse.com/docs/js/guide#queries-basic-queries but it's not helping very much and I can't get it. How that could be achieved?

edit:

```
q1.find({
    success: function(results){     

    for (var x in results){
        x.helper1 = 'foo';
    }

     response.success(results);
    },
    error: function(error){

    }
});
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In JavaScrpt everything is easy. As far as I know, those parse-objects are stored in the form of a JSON object. (equivalently literal objects in JavaScript).

In JavaScript, If you'd like to add an additional property (playing role of a class member) to an existing object, it's enough to use this code.

```
var myobj = /* This is that parse-object */

// Add property helper1
myobj.helper1 = 'foo';

// Add property helper2
myobj.helper2 = 'bar';
```

For removing those properties, use this code.

```
// Remove property helper1
delete myobj.helper1;

// Remove property helper2
delete myobj.helper2;
```

Equivalently, you can use `[]` to create and access a property.

```
// Add property help1
myobj['helper1'] = 'foo';

// Access it
console.log(myobj['helper1']);
```

Comment: I have updated my question. I tried to use that approach via loop, but when I read that it's `undefinded`.

Comment: Oh, and I use `console.log(array[i].get("helper1"));` to read

Comment: @jeand'arme Use `results[x].helper1 = 'foo';` in that loop.

Comment: @jeand'arme Also for reading a property don't use `get()` method.

Comment: Okay, I've done like You said and use `console.log(array[i].helper1);` to get this. Still undefined. How can I send Your private message with link to the page in question?

Comment: @jeand'arme What's the `array` variable? Update your question and post more relevant codes.

Comment: @jeand'arme Also Stack Overflow doesn't have private messages. Everything is public. Free for all `:)`

Comment: In `Parse.Cloud.run("function", { }, { success: function(result) {}, error ...{}` variable of array is that `result` called on success

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/96482/discussion-between-hi-im-frogatto-and-jean-darme).

Answer (score 0):

I resolved that, by using @Hi I'm frogatto's answers, but it appeared that You can do that on server-side or client-side, but only locally. So when I send data with setted `helper1` or `helper2` those just vanished so I had to do that operation on client-side which exposes a bit of business logic.

My question is still valid. Still, many of You should get helpful informations from frogatto's answers. Use my answer as a workaround.